# angular: encapsulate a Stepper Component

Tags: angular, angular-material, shadow-dom, color-picker

I have issues using together materal-stepper and a ngx-color-picker within. In a stepper, the content is to be found in a `.mat-horizontal-content-container` with `overflow: hidden`. As a consequence, the color picker is visible only within the stepper content and some parts may be invisible.

A solution I found with css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-content-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

However according to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160 `ng-deep` may not be supported soon. A solution of a post (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160#issuecomment-504642697) is to:

```
1. define a class on the component's container element
2. set the component to encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
3. wrap all styles in the component (SCSS) with the class of the component's container element
4. target any selectors that you want in the library component
```

I am new to angular, as I understand it I should wrap the MatStepper into a custom component, by disabling the shadow dom within it.

Is that correct? How are we suppose to wrap an existing component by keeping all its features?

Thx.

Comment: This is the correct approach. In your component declaration add ViewEncapsulation.None. You'll have to import ViewEncapsulation. Now you can overwrite NG material css.

Comment: I also found that the css rule can be defined in the `style.css` file (the main application css file), in this case it does not need the `ng-deep`. This is great as I can apply it to many steppers with only css. However I don't know why the `style.css` can go through the shadow dom?

Comment: No that's not how it works. The reason your style.css is working now is because you turned your view encapsulation off. You should create your own css file like: MyComponent.css/scss and put your styles in there. That will work now too.